# Не работает код на С

Tags: c

По заданию нужно удалить из строки элементы с нечетным количеством символов.
Ошибка точно где-то в внутри условии if (c % 2 == 0). Скорее всего в этой строке str = str + i - c. Но я не понимаю, почему она не работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char strr[100] = "aba afff e fu ", helpp[100];
    char *str = strr;
    char *help = helpp;
    int c = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(strr); i++)
    {
        if (strr[i] == ' ')
        {
            if (c % 2 == 0)
            {
                str = str + i - c;
                for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
                {
                    *help++ = *str;
                    str = str + 1;
                }
            }
            c = 0;
        }
        c++;
    }
    *help++ = '\0';
    puts(helpp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я попробовал выполнить вашу задачу. У меня получился такой код. Все объяснения сделаны комментариями.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    // Инициализация исходной строки и строки для новых слов
    char str[100] = "aba afff e fu ", new_str[100];
    // Указатели на начало исходной и новой строк
    char* ptr = str;
    char* new_ptr = new_str;
    // Переменная для хранения длины текущего слова
    int word_length = 0;

    // Проход по всей строке
    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        // Если текущий символ - пробел, то слово закончилось
        if (*ptr == ' ')
        {
            // Проверяем длину слова на четность
            if (word_length % 2 == 0)
            {
                // Если длина слова четная, то копируем его в новую строку
                memcpy(new_ptr, ptr - word_length, word_length);
                // Сдвигаем указатель на следующую позицию после скопированного слова
                new_ptr += word_length;
                // Добавляем пробел после слова в новой строке
                *new_ptr++ = ' ';
            }
            // Сбрасываем длину слова для следующего слова
            word_length = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Если текущий символ не пробел, то увеличиваем длину текущего слова
            word_length++;
        }
        // Переходим к следующему символу в исходной строке
        ptr++;
    }

    // Проверяем последнее слово на четность длины
    if (word_length % 2 == 0)
    {
        // Если длина слова четная, то копируем его в новую строку
        memcpy(new_ptr, ptr - word_length, word_length);
        // Сдвигаем указатель на следующую позицию после скопированного слова
        new_ptr += word_length;
    }
    // Добавляем нулевой символ в конец новой строки
    *new_ptr = '\0';

    // Выводим новую строку на экран
    printf("%s", new_str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое вам за ваш код. Я просмотрел и логика решения у меня такая же. Прошу прощение за непрезентабельность кода. Не знаете ли вы, почему команда str = str + i - c в моем коде не работает?

Comment: @Kyteraade честно говоря нет.